# Canon Pixma MG8200 Printer Drivers on 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, printing, canon

I have a Canon Pixma MG8200 printer- are there drivers for 18.04 LTS? There were drivers for older versions of Ubuntu ~12 or so. The usual "Add Printer" route can't find drivers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where to find the Linux drivers for Canon printers. The official Canon site doesn't even have a Linux driver for my printer. Luckily, the Gutenprint driver works well for Canon printers. You can install it as follows:

```
sudo apt install printer-driver-gutenprint
```

Then, connect your printer via USB to the computer, and go to Settings > Printers (Pic 1). If you don't see your printer there, add it. If you see the printer, click on the gear icon next to it, and select printer details. On the new window that opens up (Pic 2), select Select from database..., and fin your printer model under the Canon drivers (Pic 3). Once you save that, your printer should work :)

I tested this solution both in Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 using a Canon PIXMA MP470 series printer, and I could see an entry for the Canon PIXMA MG8200 series printer too (see Pic 3).

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

[image: Pic 3]

Answer (score 1):

use the Canon drivers; so go here https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg8240.aspx?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:13-866172&os=Linux%20(64-bit)&language=EN and click to download the debian package there; it will come down as cnijfilter-mg8200series-3.60-1-deb.tar.gz. Your printer has lasted well: 7yrs old

open a terminal; copy each line of command below; paste it into the terminal; hit the ENTER key after each paste

```
cd Downloads

tar -zxvf cnijfilter-mg8200series-3.60-1-deb.tar.gz

cd cnijfilter-mg8200series-3.60-1-deb

sudo ./install.sh
```

the last command is the install script; watch as it runs as it will ask you questions; we hope all goes well